# Post username and password to URL from a sh script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to create a batch sript to check if Internet is responding. If is responding then do nothing, but if no responding then post usernname and password to a URL. Bellow and example that I want to do, I know that the script is wrong and is for this rason that I am asking for help.

```
#!/bin/sh
if ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null 
then 
 do={/tool fetch http-method=post http-data="username=myuser&&password=mypass" url="https://secure.etecsa.net:8443//LoginServlet" }
else 
echo 0 
fi
```

Comment: Are you looking for `curl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl to post your message:

```
#!/bin/bash

######################################################################
# Script Configuration
######################################################################
TARGET_URL="https://secure.etecsa.net:8443/LoginServlet"

# Set the internet server to be verified (Change this as needed)
VERIFICATION_SERVER="8.8.8.8"

# Verification Timeout (seconds)
VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS=1

# User Data
data="username=myuser&&password=mypass"

# Checks if internet is reachable
ping -c 1 -W ${VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS} ${VERIFICATION_SERVER} &> /dev/null

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  # Internet not detected,
  # post username and password to URL
  curl --insecure -X POST ${TARGET_URL} -d "${data}"
else
  # Internet active
  echo "Internet is active."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null will return 0 if the ping is successful.  0 is FALSE, so the then block will not run.  You need to swap your then and else blocks.  There are other issues with the script, but this should answer you question.